# subtract time. Day is same

Tags: php, date, time, subtraction

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Subtract time in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5463549/subtract-time-in-php)

How can i subtract time? the day remains the same. i just need to subtract two time.

Date = 2011-04-26
Starttime = 12:39:53
Endtime = 14:34:28

now i need to calculate the time difference between Endtime and Starttime.

Thanks

Comment: nope... this is not the answer i was looking for... :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
 <?php
    $lasttime = strtotime("-67 minutes"); // for instance
    $currentdate = strtotime("now");
    $lastact = date("Y-m-d g:i:s a", $lasttime);
    $now = date("Y-m-d g:i:s a", $currentdate);
    $daycheck = date("d", $now) - date("d", $lastact);
    $minutecheck = date("i", $now) - date("i", $lastact);
    $difference = $currentdate - $lasttime;
 ?>
```

Comment: im not sure it works.. it gives something like this 6166. Start time: 09:47:33 End time: 11:30:19

Comment: Those are the seconds between your 2 dates?