# How to get the total hour from starting time to end time in php

Tags: php, datetime, time

How can I get the total hour from start time to end time.

```
   $start_time = '11:00:00 PM'; // as of 07/08/2013
   $end_time   = '01:00:00 AM'; // as of 08/08/2013
```

Then output should be:

```
   $total = '02:00:00'; // 12 hour format
```

Comment: This link might have the solution you're looking for:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5463549/subtract-time-in-php

Comment: Date::diff is not accurate. When i have the given above it gives me wrong output

Comment: Are you restricted to only supplying the hours? If you can supply the dates along with the times then it'll output the result you're looking for. Ex: echo date_create('07/08/2013 11:00:00 PM')->diff(date_create('08/08/2013 01:00:00 AM'))->format('%h');

Comment: yes. I use timepicker only the date is not included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the date strings to time values, then subtract to get the difference in seconds between the two, then simply divide by 3600 to get the difference in hours:

```
$t1 = strtotime('2013-08-07 23:00:00');
$t2 = strtotime('2013-08-08 01:00:00');
$differenceInSeconds = $t2 - $t1;
$differenceInHours = $differenceInSeconds / 3600;
```

Comment: I use only timepicker, date is not included in the input field.

Comment: Having this given `$start_time` = 11:00:00 PM and `$end_time` = 01:00:00 AM. It gives me -22 output

Comment: OK, add this line at the end:  if($differenceInHours<0) { $differenceInHours += 24; }

Comment: how about if i want it to 12hour format "HH:mm:ss"? not only the hour. + 1

Comment: add this line (after the previous line above):  $total= $differenceInHours . ":00:00";

Comment: ow! when my input 11:30:00 AM to 01:00:00 PM it gives me 1.5:00:00 to to make it 01:30:00?

Comment: OK.  Disregard the last line I gave you , and use these instead:       $hours = floor($differenceInHours);
    $minutes = ($differenceInHours-$hours)*60;
    $total=$hours . ":" . $minutes . "00";

Comment: I'll leave that to you as an exercise.

Comment: Is that something like this? `$seconds = ($hours-$minutes)*3600;` honestly i dont get it

Comment: I dont reallly get it. Could you provide me a hint how to do that? i really need to finish my project.

Comment: You were close.   Something like this should work:
$h1=$differenceInHours;
 $h2=floor($h1); 
 $m1=($h1-$h2)*60; 
 $m2=floor($m1); 
 $s=($m1-$m2)*60; 
 $total=$h2 . ":" . $m2 . ":" . $s;

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find out the total time and you only have time values go for this. //24 hour format

```
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) { //array contains your sorted times like [H:i]
        $a = $array[$i]. " " .date("Y/m/d");
        $array[$i] = $a;
    }
    
    $total=0;
    for ($i = count($array); $i>1; $i--){
        if ($array[$i-1] < $array[$i-2]){
            $array[$i-1] = strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($array[$i-1]));
            $z = "a";
        }
        $a = strtotime($array[$i-1]);
        $b = strtotime($array[$i-2]);
        $diff = $a - $b;    
        $hours = ceil($diff / (24*60));
        $total += date("H", $hours);
    }
if ($z == "a"){
    $total += date("H", ceil(strtotime($array[0]) / (24*60)));
}
```