# Find the difference between to times and minus an integer

Tags: php, mysql

Currently I'm creating a table that holds timesheet information, I'm trying to display the amount of time worked minus the break. I was wondering if there a way to find the difference in time between the start time and end time, then minus the amount of time for the break. The only problem I have right now is the break is stored as an integer of the number of minutes the break was. Is there a way of doing thing without have to store the break as a time value?

This is the code I have to display the number of hours worked between start and end:

```
<?php while($row = $approvedTimes->fetch()){ ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $row['userFirst'] . " ". $row['userLast'];  ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['companyName'];  ?></td>
      <td><?php echo date('Y-M-d',strtotime($row['timeDate']));  ?></td>
      <td><?php echo date("h:i a",strtotime($row['timeStart'])); $start = new DateTime($row['timeStart']);  ?></td>
      <td><?php echo date("h:i a",strtotime($row['timeEnd'])); $end = new DateTime($row['timeEnd'] );  ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['timeBreak'] . " Min."; $break = $row['timeBreak']; ?></td>
      <td><?php $hours = $start->diff($end); echo $hours->format('%h hours %i min.'); ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: You already have answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5463549/subtract-time-in-php

Answer (score 3):

`strtotime()` returns a unix timestamp (seconds since Jan 1/1970), so the math is simple:

```
$seconds_worked = strtotime($end) - strtotime($start) - ($break_in_minutes * 60);
```

From there you can convert into h/m/s with relative ease.