# PHP Minus/Subtract Hour/Minute strings formated H:i

Tags: php, function, datetime

I have a PHP function that when given two values Hours/Minutes, it adds the two value, for example:

> 00:20 + 00:15 = 00:35

Here is the function:

```
function sumHoursAndMinutes() {
    $i = 0;
    foreach(func_get_args() as $time) {
        sscanf($time, '%d:%d', $hour, $min);
        $i += $hour * 60 + $min;
    }

    if( $h = floor($i / 60) ) {
        $i %= 60;
    }

    return sprintf('%02d:%02d', $h, $i);
}
// Usage: sumHoursAndMinutes("00:20", "00:15");
```

> Output: "00:35"

How can I achieve the same thing doing subtraction, Example: 00:20 - 00:15 = 00:05

Comment: `Usage: sumHoursAndMinutes("00:20", "00:15");` - how is this valid syntax when you have no function params?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Subtract time in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5463549/subtract-time-in-php)

Comment: @treyBake the function uses func_get_args()

Comment: Ah I see - missed that - as a note, much better to use params :)

Comment: I tried the answers in that question, it is different, couldn't find what i was looking for @treyBake

Comment: @user3475530 is none of the answers correct? What are we missing in our answers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might look like a long approach, but I'd personally just convert it into minutes. This makes it easier to handle and I used a reformat method for the following purpose: If your `substractTimeFromTime` or `addTimeToTime` returns something `<0`, you know, something was wrong with your inputs or it just doesn't make any sense in your context. Also, you need to verify that the times are valid, since `01:99` would be a valid input by now. I was just assuming you do the verification before.

```
function reformatMinutes($minutes)
{
    $hours = intval($minutes/60);
    $minutes -= $hours*60;
    return sprintf("%02d:%02d",$hours,$minutes);
}

function addTimeToTime($time1, $time2)
{
    $time1 = explode(":",$time1);
    $time2 = explode(":",$time2);
    $sumOfMinutes = intval($time1[0])*60+intval($time2[0])*60+intval($time1[1])+intval($time2[1]);
    return $sumOfMinutes;

}

function substractTimeFromTime($basis,$subtract)
{
    $basis = explode(":",$basis);
    $subtract = explode(":",$subtract);
    $remainingMinutes = intval($basis[0])*60-intval($subtract[0])*60+intval($basis[1])-intval($subtract[1]);
    return $remainingMinutes;       
}

$resultPlus = addTimeToTime("01:10","00:15");
$resultMinus = substractTimeFromTime("01:30","00:15");
echo reformatMinutes($resultPlus);
echo reformatMinutes($resultMinus);
```

This outputs:

```
01:25
01:15
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use date() and strtotime().

Remember to set the time zone back to your default again after.
We need UTC time zone to not have to worry about DST or time zone difference.

```
$a = "00:20";
$b = "00:15";

date_default_timezone_set("UTC");

echo date("H:i", strtotime($a) + strtotime($b));
echo "\n\n";
echo date("H:i", strtotime($a) - strtotime($b));

date_default_timezone_set("Your_default_timezone");

//00:35
//00:05
```

https://3v4l.org/kIVlI

---

If you need to calculate the hours and minutes manually from strtotime.

If it's addition you want to do you need to remove strtotime("00:00")*2 from the result because we are using Unix times.
Then I use str_pad to format the hours and minutes.

```
$a = "00:20";
$b = "02:15";

date_default_timezone_set("UTC");

// If addition
$diff = strtotime($a) + strtotime($b) - strtotime("00:00")*2;
$hours = floor($diff /3600);
$minutes = ($diff -($hours *3600))/60;

echo str_pad($hours,2,0, STR_PAD_LEFT) . ":" . str_pad($minutes,2,0, STR_PAD_LEFT) ;


echo "\n\n";


//If subtraction
$diff = strtotime($a) - strtotime($b);
$hours = floor($diff /3600);
$minutes = ($diff -($hours *3600))/60;

echo str_pad($hours,2,0, STR_PAD_LEFT) . ":" . str_pad($minutes,2,0, STR_PAD_LEFT) ;


//date_default_timezone_set("Your_default_timezone");

//02:35
//-2:05
```

Comment: While I find this a really neat solution, you have to point out that it will return (not really nicely detectable) garbage if `$b > $a` in the `-` line. Also this doesn't work with `hours > 24` and has some problems since it's treated as a real date.

Comment: @maio290 that is true. I think/thought OP only needed a simple calculation. But it can easily be recoded to handle the situations you list.

Comment: it doesn't work when i have values like 114:30 - 2:45

Comment: @user3475530 that's a long way from what your question is. Next time try to ask a question with relevant numbers

Answer (score 0):

Either write an almost identical function for minus instead of plus or add an optional Boolean parameter that defaults to plus but can be set to minus.

Comment: I changed the plus to minus but I couldn't get the desired result, seems like I can't get the math right :)